# Haskell string manipulation. Non-exhaustive patterns in function error

Tags: string, parsing, haskell

I am trying to solve a simple problem on HackerRank and am receiving the error in the title. The problem asks to take in a string and reduce it by removing adjacent pairs of letters. So "aabcdd" => "bc" for example. Here's my code:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    line <- getLine
    putStrLn (reduce' line)

reduce' :: String -> String
reduce' [] = []
reduce' (x0:x1:xs)
    | x1:xs == [] = [x0]
    | x0 == x1 = reduce' xs
    | otherwise = x0 : x1 : reduce' xs
```

I am confused because I think I have the edge cases covered. I don't want an answer to the problem, I just want to know why I am getting the error. Thanks!

Comment: It's been awhile since I've written Haskell, but iirc, your last case will only match exactly 3 characters. If the string has 1 or 2 elements, it won't match.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: no two elements `xs` is the tail of the list.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh right. So just 1 element.

Comment: Enabling warnings (`-Wall`) would detect the missing case(s). Strongly recommended.

Comment: Also `x1:xs == []` is simply a bug it seems; that conditional is always false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not matching the case where you have only one element in the list

```
reduce' :: String -> String
reduce' []   = []
reduce' [x]  = [x] 
reduce' (x0:x1:xs)
    | x0 == x1 = reduce' xs
    | otherwise = x0 : x1 : reduce' xs
```

This `| x1:xs == [] = [x0]` is the pattern matching added, so there is no need to check in the guards.

Comment: Note that the first two cases together can be written as one `reduce' x = x` if you put it *after* the `x0:x1:xs` case.